# Pasting values into DatetimePicker

Tags: c#, copy-paste, datetimepicker

I have DateTimePicker controls in my C# Windows application. Some of them are formatted to show date while others show time.

A user wants to click on some textbox field which contains time in text format like `14:25:56` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Then he would like to click on the DateTimePicker and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste this time into date in DateTimePicker.

It doesn't work by default. Is it possible to make something like it working at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something similar about a year ago with pasting values into a data grid. I handled it by putting an event handler on the **KeyDown** event of the control that you want to paste the value into, then you can use the event args to check which of the characters (in this case, **V**) is pressed and which modifier keys (**CTRL**, **SHIFT**, **ALT**, etc.) are pressed.

Once you know **CTRL+V** was pressed, you can create some code to parse through the string returned by `Clipboard.GetText();` using `DateTime.Parse();` as [defined on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) and store the value in the date-time picker. Here is what I got. You will want to do some validation to make sure the text is in the right format. You can do this with `DateTime.TryParse();` instead of `DateTime.Parse()` like I am using.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(Clipboard.GetText());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. I'll try it out.